# How to read a 2d triangle array from txt file?

Tags: c++, arrays, file-handling

I want to read 2d triangle array from a txt file.

```
1
8 4
2 6 9
8 5 9 6
```

I wrote this code. At the end I wanted to print it out if I got the array right. When I run it it does not print the array, but in debug it prints. So there is a problem, but I cannot find it. Sometimes it gives segmentation fault, but I dont understand.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>


int main() {

    std::ifstream input_file("input_file.txt");

    int size{1};
    int **arr = (int**)malloc(3*sizeof(int));

    int *lineArr = (int*) malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    int temp{};

    int index{};

    while(input_file >> temp){
        lineArr[index] = temp;
        index++;
        if(index == size){
            index = 0;
            arr[size-1] = new int[size-1];
            for(int i{}; i<size; i++){
                arr[size-1][i] = lineArr[i];
            }
            size++;
            lineArr = (int*) realloc(lineArr, size*sizeof(int));
        }
    }

    input_file.close();

    for(int a{}; a<size-1; a++){
        for(int j{}; j<=a; j++){
            std::cout << arr[a][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which web site or textbook suggested that you use `malloc` in C++ code? You need to stop using that web site or textbook to learn C++, you're not learning C++ correctly. Additionally: nothing in the shown code requires anything to be allocated. In modern C++ everything that the shown code does can be done using `std::vector`. See your C++ textbook for more information.

Comment: `(int**)malloc(3*sizeof(int))` should presumably be `(int**)malloc(3*sizeof(int*))` (or as this is c++ `new` would be simpler and less error prone, or even just `std::vector`)

Comment: You may soon learn why `malloc` and `realloc` are almost never used in C++ code.  `(int**)malloc(3*sizeof(int))` probably allocates enough storage for 1.5 pointers.  Instead try the simple `new int[3];`.

Comment: Instead of using `malloc`, I highly recommend using `std::vector` and `std::vector::push_back`.  Let the vector manage the memory for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use vector instead of malloc. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream input_file("input_file.txt");
    vector<string> numbers;
    if (input_file.is_open()) {
        string line;
        while (getline(input_file, line)) {
           numbers.push_back(line);
        }
        input_file.close();
    }

    for (vector<string>::iterator t=numbers.begin(); t!=numbers.end(); ++t) 
    {
        cout<<*t<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```